# Bootstrap tab panel - Como ir para uma tab específica?

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap

Eu tenho, em `PHP`, um método cujo código retorna valores, passando-os para uma `View`, conforme bloco abaixo:

```
return view('PesquisaView')
     ->with('clientes',$resultadoClientes)
     ->with('advs',$resultadoAdvs)
     ->with('bps',$resultadoBPs)
     ->with('mensagemDoUploadRemessa',$avisoUpload);
```

Entretanto, esta View tem várias guias (tabs) baseando-se no framework Boostrap e o 'return' exibe a View na primeira tab, aquela que foi definida como 'active' no início do uso da página.

Eu gostaria de que a instrução 'return', que provoca a abertura da View, mostrasse diretamente a guia que eu desejo, e não a 'default'.
No caso a de 'id' 'IdPaneCitiPesquisarRemessa'.

O código html que define as guias é

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
     <li><a href="#idQExpert" data-toggle="tab">QExpert</a></li>
     <li>
       <a href="#idPaneCitiPesquisarRemessa" data-toggle="tab">Citibank - Remessa</a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#idPaneCitiPesquisar" data-toggle="tab">Citibank - Retorno</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

### Atualização:

Aproveitando a sugestão valiosa do @Virgilio Novic (assim como as de @wmengue e de @massreuy), alterei meu código para o seguinte:

Método no PHP:

```
$tab = 2;
return view('PesquisaView')
 ->with('clientes',$resultadoClientes)
 ->with('advs',$resultadoAdvs)
 ->with('bps',$resultadoBPs)
 ->with('mensagemDoUploadRemessa',$avisoUpload);
 ->with('tab',$tab);
```

Marcação HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
 <li class="{{$tab==1?'active':''}}"><a href="#idQExpert" data-toggle="tab">QExpert</a></li>
 <li class="{{$tab==2?'active':''}}"><a href="#idPaneCitiPesquisarRemessa" data-toggle="tab">Citibank - Remessa</a>
 </li>
 <li class="{{$tab==3?'active':''}}">
    <a href="#idPaneCitiPesquisar" data-toggle="tab">Citibank - Retorno</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Após executar o método, ele retorna o valor 2 para a variável $tab, a View blade aceita o parâmetro e realça a guia 'Citibank - Remessa' (a guia do meio, na imagem abaixo, que está com o fundo branco), mas vejam que o conteúdo, que é um 'form' html, não aparece.

[image: Tela após o return do código PHP]
Contudo, se as guias forem clicadas, para troca de página, seja a primeira ou a terceira e, de volta à segunda, aí sim o formulário é renderizado, conforme nova imagem abaixo:
[image: Imagem correta, que deveria estar exibida após o retorno do método]

Isto é, o evento 'click' não acontece ao tornar-se a classe 'active' via código.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer um tratamento em seu código, enviando um parâmetro para a view que determinará a tab ativa.

```
<li class="active">
```

O parâmetro dirá quando essa classe deverá entrar ou não. Ou se precisar que seja sempre fixa, basta colocar na tab que necessita.

Comment: confesso que não sei fazer isto. Imagino que seja algo do tipo ...->with('classe','<li class="active">')..., mas não sei como aproveitar sua ideia.

Comment: @MauroSimoes Sua dúvida é como enviar isso do Laravel para a view ou como tratar o parâmetro enviado ele para colocar a classe?

Comment: Confesso que não vejo como passar no 'with' e, na View-Blade, como aproveitar o que chega do PHP.

Comment: @MauroSimoes na view do blade você pode acessar a variável que passou pelo php assim: {{ $nomeDaVariavelUsadaNoWith }} assim você irá recuperar o que foi passado do php para a view-blade

Comment: terei de testar isset($nomeDaVariavelUsadaNoWith) antes de aplicar a classe, não?

Comment: @MauroSimoes Você pode utilizar a diretiva do Laravel isset/endisset pode ver maiores informações em https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#control-structures

Answer (score 1):

Faz o seguinte, no seu controller, adiciona uma variável a mais contendo a tab que deseja marcar como ativa, neste caso:

```
return view('PesquisaView')
->with('clientes',$resultadoClientes)
->with('advs',$resultadoAdvs)
->with('bps',$resultadoBPs)
->with('mensagemDoUploadRemessa',$avisoUpload)
->with('activeTab', $activeTab);
```

Em seguida, crie uma nova view com um tratamento para receber este valor. Por exemplo `activeTab.blade.php com` o seguinte código:

```
@if($params['tab'] == 'idQExpert')
    active
@elseif($params['tab'] == 'idPaneCitiPesquisarRemessa')
    active
@elseif($params['tab'] == 'idPaneCitiPesquisar')
    active
@endif
```

E por fim, na sua view principal, em cada um dos elementos `<li>` adicione da seguinte forma:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="@include('layouts/activeTab', ['params' => ['tab' => $activeTab]])">
        <a href="#idQExpert" data-toggle="tab">QExpert</a>
    </li>
    <li class="@include('layouts/activeTab', ['params' => ['tab' => $activeTab]])">
        <a href="#idPaneCitiPesquisarRemessa" data-toggle="tab">Citibank - Remessa</a>
    </li>
    <li class="@include('layouts/activeTab', ['params' => ['tab' => $activeTab]])">
        <a href="#idPaneCitiPesquisar" data-toggle="tab">Citibank - Retorno</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Isto provavelmente vai resolver seu problema.

Comment: Fiz duas correções, para testar seu código: primeiro, acrescentei um fechamento de colchete nas linhas do @include, porque estava faltando; segundo, retirei a referência à pasta 'layouts' porque minhas Views ficam mesmo na mesma pasta Views. Entretanto, ao abrir, o código está reclamando da variável $activeTab estar vazia, porque ela só é preenchida no 'return' do PHP, assunto central de nossa discussão. Ou seja, acredito que eu tenha que fazer isset($activeTab) antes.

Comment: Desculpe pelos erros de sintax, eu fiz tudo aqui mesmo editor do stackoverflow. Sobre o erro da variável, se esta sua view for chamada apenas por este método do controller não precisa, porque no controller vc sempre vai enviar. Se for utilizar ela em outras situações, ai sim, convem colocar um `isset` mesmo.

Comment: optei por outra abordagem, porque não consegui fazer funcionar. Reestruturei do zero.

Comment: (optei por outra abordagem, mas ainda não consegui fazer funcionar, bem entendido)

Comment: Beleza, qualquer coisa avisa aqui. Qualquer coisa entra no grupo do slack laravel-br

Answer (score 1):

Mande a informação que precisa que a `tab` seja a padrão no momento do carregamento:

***Código***

```
$tab = 2;
return view('PesquisaView')
     ->with('clientes',$resultadoClientes)
     ->with('advs',$resultadoAdvs)
     ->with('bps',$resultadoBPs)
     ->with('mensagemDoUploadRemessa',$avisoUpload);
     ->with('tab',(is_null($tab)) ? 1 : $tab);
```

---

E no código do `blade` faça:

***Html***

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li @if($tab == 1) {{ 'class="active"' }} @endif ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li @if($tab == 2) {{ 'class="active"' }} @endif ><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li @if($tab == 3) {{ 'class="active"' }} @endif ><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Virgílio, não funcionou. Apenas ficava as 'tabs' sozinhas, sem destaque e a tela sem conteúdo. Modifiquei seu código numa das linhas, mudando para a condição em ternário, para <li class="{{$tab=='1' ? 'active':''}}" ><a href="#idQExpert" data-toggle="tab">QExpert</a></li> e a tela continua sem conteúdo, mas a 'tab' desejada ficou realçada.

Comment: Quis dizer: eu mudei as linhas do html totalmente. Uma das linhas ficou como o exemplo acima.

Comment: @MauroSimoes o código acima é a realidade do que precisa, edite sua questão e coloque todo código html e o controller por favor deixa eu ver onque esta acontecendo?